# Angular showing "Cannot read property 'friends' of null"

Tags: node.js, angular, httpclient

Hi I am trying trying to get data from my nodejs backend to angular. And i get the below error message in nodejs

```
Cannot read property 'friends' of null
    at UserModel.findOne.select.lean.exec
```

The Api Works fine, if i try to use in postman. But when used in angular i get the error message in nodejs

The server side code is:

```
let findFriends = ()=>{
        return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
            UserModel.findOne({userId: req.body.userId || req.query.userId})
                .select('-__v -_id -password')
                .lean()
                .exec((err, userFriends)=>{
                    console.log(userFriends.friends.length)
                    if(err){
                        logger.error(err.message, ' friendsController: getAllNonFriends, findFriends', 5)
                        let apiResponse = response.generate(true, `Failed to Find Friends`, 500, null)
                        reject(apiResponse)
                    }else {
                        if(userFriends.friends.length !== 0){
                            resolve(userFriends.friends)
                        }else {
                            resolve(userFriends)
                        }  
                    }
                })
        })  
    } // end find requests
```

the code in angular:

```
public allNonFriends: any = ()=>{
    this.http.getNonFriendsList(this.currentUser).subscribe(
      (apiResponse)=>{
        console.log(apiResponse)
        if(apiResponse.status === 200){
          console.log(apiResponse.data)
        } else {
          console.log(apiResponse.message)
        }
      },
      (err)=>{
        console.log(err)
      }
    )
  } // end all non friends
```

Comment: Could you show `getNonFriendsList()` method please?

Comment: Can you move the `console.log` in the server code to be inside the `else`.  There may be an error from the `exec`, but the error handling code isn't being hit.

Comment: see the getNonFriendsList() method -----

public getNonFriendsList(userId): Observable<any>{
    return this.http.get(`${this.baseurl}/friends/get/non-friends`, userId)
   } // end get non friedns list

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I change the parameter from body to query and it worked